# Editing an existing tag value on a Azure KeyVault secret version

Tags: azure, powershell, tags, azure-keyvault

My aim to create a new version of a particular secret in my KeyVault and copy all the tags of the current version to the new one. However while doing that, I want to change the value of one of those tags and keep the rest of them as it is.

```
$CurrentSecret = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $VaultName -Name $SecretName -IncludeVersions
$ActiveSecret = $CurrentSecret[0]

$NewSecret = New-AzServiceBusKey -Name $SecretName -ResourceGroup $ResourceGroupName -Namespace $SBNameSpace -RegenerateKey PrimaryKey

$NewSecretValue = $NewSecret.PrimaryKey

$SecureStringNewKey = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $NewSecretValue -AsPlainText -Force
$EndDate = (Get-Date).AddMonths(12)

$SecretObject = Set-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $VaultName -Name $SecretName -SecretValue $SecureStringNewKey -Expires $EndDate -ContentType $ActiveSecret.ContentType -Tag $ActiveSecret.Tags

PS E:\XXX> $SecretObject.Tags

Name                           Value
----                           -----
KeyType                        Primary
SecretType                     ServiceBusKey
```

I want to change the value of "KeyType" to "Secondary" and keep everything the same.

I tried the following but it overrides the value as expected :

```
$Tags = @{ 'KeyType' = 'Secondary'}

$New = Update-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $VaultName -Name $SecretName -Expires $EndDate -ContentType $ActiveSecret.ContentType -Enable $True -Tag $Tags -PassThru

$New.Tags

Name                           Value
----                           -----
KeyType                        Secondary
```

Eventually the tags in the original version would increase to around 10. I am not looking forward to a way of specifying everything in an enumerator as hardcore values in code while updating the tags.
I tried looking at $New.Tags.KeyType. (Length,Clone,GetEnumerator,GetHashCode,CompareTo,Contains,CopyTo,EndsWith,Equals)
but couldn't find a way to just update just the value of KeyType tag to 'Secondary'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if I understand your meaning correctly, you have already created the new version of the secret, and you want to update its `Tag` now, please try the command below after `Set-AzKeyVaultSecret`.

```
$sec = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $VaultName -Name $SecretName
$sec.Tags.KeyType = "Secondary"
Update-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $VaultName -Name $VaultName -Tag $sec.Tags
```

[image]

Or you can use the command below directly, it will also work.

```
$SecretObject = Set-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $VaultName -Name $SecretName -SecretValue $SecureStringNewKey -Expires $EndDate -ContentType $ActiveSecret.ContentType -Tag $ActiveSecret.Tags
$SecretObject.Tags.KeyType = "Secondary"
Update-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $VaultName -Name mySecret123 -Tag $SecretObject.Tags
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, your solution works! !